# Can I combine Vue JS with Laravel and bootstrap?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I would create simple website with forum. I would use Vue JS with Laravel and Bootstrap. Is it good combination? Vue JS is necessary for me, Laravel and Bootstrap can be changed for something else, but I don't know what could be better to use in this situation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> By default, fresh Laravel applications contain an ExampleComponent.vue Vue component located in the resources/js/components directory. Single file components provide a very convenient approach to building
>   JavaScript driven applications.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend#writing-vue-components                           
 It is a good approach. Components made in Vue are much easier to handle, as opposed to repeating the same code in different blade templates.